# CALayer shadow performance

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, calayer, shadow

I have a grid CALayer (with a parent NSView, enclosed by an NSScrollView) that contains a bunch of sublayers, each sublayer drawing an image. When I disable the shadows for the sublayers, the performance is great. However, as soon as I enable them, drawing starts to lag badly.

Are there any things I can do to improve this? I've heard of using `shouldRasterize` on iOS to improve shadow performance, but that property is not available on OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you turned on layer-backing? Then the drawing contents would be cached and that might improve performance.

Comment: I assume you are setting the layer's shadow property... have you tried drawing the shadow into the layer's background property with quartz?

Comment: Yeah I managed to draw one using CoreGraphics that looked decent.

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming its because shadows drawn in the layer's context are cached along with everything else, unlike the layer shadow property which renders shadows dynamically. iOS has the shouldRasterize property which allows the shadow to be cached as well, but unfortunately it isn't on OS X at this moment.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem, by setting the `shadowPath` property of the CALayer I got a significant performance boost.

Comment: How exactly do you set this? What do I need to put in as a CGPathRef?

Comment: @barfoon: The outline of the view you are creating a shadow for. Obviously, this only works for opaque views and is only practical for views that can easily be described as a path (rectangular views, for instance).

Comment: @barfoon: Yea, it works easiest for things that are easy to create a path for (like most UIViews), here is a function I am using to do so for a UIImageView: http://pastebin.com/z8V8SgX8